# Qt OpenGL texture is black

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures

I need to load a texture onto a square but whenever i start te program I can't see any texture, just a black square.

Here's the code:

```
GLuint texture;

interactiveScenes::interactiveScenes(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::interactiveScenes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer();
    connect( timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()) );

    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

    lockMouse = true;

   camPosx = 2.0,  camPosy = 2.0,    camPosz = 25.0;
   camViewx = 2.0, camViewy = 2.0, camViewz = 0.0;
   camUpx = 0.0,   camUpy = 1.0,   camUpz = 0.0;

   mouseX = QCursor::pos().x();
   mouseY = QCursor::pos().y();
   setMouseTracking(true);

}

interactiveScenes::~interactiveScenes()
{
    delete ui;
}

void interactiveScenes::initializeGL()
{
    // Initialize QGLWidget (parent)
    QGLWidget::initializeGL();

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // White canvas
    glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

    // Place light
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLfloat light0_position [] = {0.1f, 0.1f, 5.0f, 0.0f};
    GLfloat light_diffuse []={ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv ( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_position );
    glLightfv ( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse );

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    img = new QImage(":/images/images.jpg", "JPG");
    if (img->isNull())
        std::cout << "error" <<std::endl;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    QImage tex = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(*img);
    if (tex.isNull())
        std::cout << "error" <<std::endl;

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
                tex.width(), tex.height(),
                0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bits() );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    timer->start(50);
}

void interactiveScenes::resizeGL(GLint width, GLint height)
{
    if ((width<=0) || (height<=0))
        return;

    //set viewport
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //set persepective
    GLdouble aspect_ratio=(GLdouble)width/(GLdouble)height;
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect_ratio, 0.1, 40.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void interactiveScenes::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    // store current matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix( );

    gluLookAt(camPosx ,camPosy ,camPosz,
        camViewx,camViewy,camViewz,
        camUpx, camUpy, camUpz );

    //Draw Axes
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(10.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
    glEnd();
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glColor3f( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glTexCoord2d( 0.0, 5.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f );

    glTexCoord2d( 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

    glTexCoord2d( 5.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

    glTexCoord2d( 5.0, 5.0);
    glVertex3f( 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f );
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslated(2.0, 2.0 ,-4);

    GLfloat shin[] = { 12.8f };
    GLfloat amb[] = { 0.135f, 0.2225f, 0.1575f, 0.95f };
    GLfloat diff2 [] = { 0.54f , 0.89f , 0.63f, 0.95f };
    GLfloat specular[] = { 0.316228f, 0.316228f, 0.316228f, 0.95f };

    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shin);
    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, amb);
    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diff2 );

    solidSphere(2, 25, 25);

    glPopMatrix();

    // restore current matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPopMatrix( );
}
```

The image loads fine from my resource file, i thought it was something with convertToGLFormat but that also returns an image.

Comment: Rather than displaying a texture, have you first tried to just apply color to you mesh to see if it was in the frustrum ? Also, I would recommend you to take some time to update your openGL knowledge (or if starting with openGL, not learning the legacy one). Using the fixed graphic pipeline won't bring you far nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the solution! Also about the learning of the newer openGL, I have to learn it this way for college so I'm forced to learn how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to agrum I found out the problem, I tested to see if the square would show any colors and it didn't. 
I didn't disable the lighting before applying the textures/colors.
After disabling the lighting when applying the texture everything works fine!